# why does console.read get a wrong number?

Tags: c#

why does n doesnt get the number i type in the program? I typed 1 and it got 49 :S

```
Random arrN = new Random();
int[] arr;
arr = new int[100];
int n;
bool game_result = false;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    arr[i] = arrN.Next(0, 1000);
}

Console.WriteLine("what game do you want to play?\n1- guessing one number.\n2- guessing numbers in range.\n3- exit");
n = Console.Read();
```

Comment: `Console.Read` reads `char` and char for `1` is 49 as int

Comment: int intTemp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

Comment: I copied your exact title into Google and got a lot of duplicates to this. Why didn't you just search for the answer yourself?

Comment: Use `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.Read()` and Parse it with `int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: NOTE: The duplicate I suggested may not be the clearest one to use, so my bad. There is also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308098/c-sharp-console-read-and-console-readline-problems)

Comment: you are right, thank you, sorry. im new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.Read` returns a number representing the character entered so you need to convert it:

```
var n = Console.Read();
var ch = Convert.ToChar(n);
var value = int.Parse(ch.ToString());
```

Comment: isnt there console.read for int, like i tried?

Comment: No, what happens if the user presses a letter or punctuation?

Comment: i came from c++ where it depends on the type of the var, so when my var is int i want to have something like cin which will just get the number to the var. how should i do it in my program?

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Read` returns character code, not the character itself.
This will work:

```
var ch = (char)Console.Read(); // ch will contain '1'
```