# C#, Skipping Console.ReadLine(); Console.Read(); while in loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, console.readline

If I run my code and insert correct value first time program works fine and does its job, but if I input wrong path and allow for loop to spin second time it skips `path=Console.ReadLine();` but it does not skip `j = (char)Console.Read();` same thing persist through out the remaining code.

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert path:");
    path = Console.ReadLine();

    temp1 = CheckPath(path); //checks if inserted value is legit
    if (temp1 == false) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to skip this step(by default directory will be set to Desktop)? Y/N ");
        j = (char)Console.Read(); 
        if (j.Equals('Y') || j.Equals('y')) 
        {
            path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); 
            temp1 = true; 
        }
    }
    //User inputs y/Y loop will end and exit with either path chosen by user or with desktop path
} while (!temp1);
```

`path = Console.ReadLine();` is being skipped if user fails to insert correct path. Been looking for the solution since yesterday and I have failed to find identical problem on the web. Link to full code: [Code.](http://www.sourcepod.com/ljovzq97-49064)

Comment: Have you stepped through it? It's probably just the order in which you're assigning your bool and path values. Every time they're evaluated, hover over them and check if that's the value you'd expect to see.

Comment: @DeeMac I've been debugging this code like crazy. It does what is stated  on original post.

Comment: apparently Consol.Read() add a carriage return to the input, and that carriage return make Console.ReadLine() skip check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162670/reading-two-characters-in-c-sharp

Comment: @SeraphimFoA Let me try that right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call isn't being skipped - the problem is that `Console.Read()` will only return after the user has hit return - although it will only *consume* the first character it reads. So suppose that (when prompted about skipping) the user enters:

```
Nfoo
```

and then hits return... the value of `path` in the next iteration will be `foo`.

The simplest fix is probably to convert your `Console.Read()` call into `Console.ReadLine()` and just handle the situation where the user types more than one character.

Comment: j = (char)Console.Read();  is not being skipped. While path = Console.ReadLine(); is.

Comment: And that was due to Console.Read(); once I've converted it into Console.ReadLine(); it worked. Thanks. Please do explain why is that?

Comment: @Carl: I explained it in the answer... Console.Read doesn't complete until the user hits return.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding but I am trying to learn as much as possible. So please do elaborate, since I actually  hit return (return= enter?).

Comment: @Carl: You hit enter, but `Console.Read()` doesn't consume that - it only consumes a single character of input. So if you type `"foo<return>"`, it will consume the `f`, and then the next call to `Console.ReadLine()` will consume the "oo<return>".

Answer (score 3):

It's much more useful to use `Console.ReadKey` for that - it will read exactly one key, and will not require you to press enter.